# How can I use a service to configure another service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt, asp.net-identity

I'm configurating a AuthenticationService in my application, with JwtBearer .

I abstracted the JWT configuration to a service, to use it throughout the application. So, that's my code.

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<JWTService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{   
    options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim("Profession"));
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = ...;
});
```

```
public class JWTService
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public JWTService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public TokenValidationParameters Config()
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateActor = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            ValidAudience = _configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = _configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:SecretKey"]))
        };
    }
}
```

So, how can I get the JWTService to use it as a parameter of AddJwtBearer, with Config method?
I managed to do this using builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetServices, but I read that this is not recommended.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a delegate which will be called when the service is resolved which can then also have other services you need, like `IConfiguration` provided to it so that you can dynamically configure the options before they are used:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", p => p.RequireAuthenticatedUser().RequireClaim("Profession"));
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services
    .AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Configure<IConfiguration>((options, configuration) =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateActor = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            ValidAudience = configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtBearerTokenSettings:SecretKey"])),
        };
    });
```